# How best to keep bumbling, non-technical managers at bay and still deliver good work?

Tags: project-management, software, engineering

This question may be considered subjective (I got a warning) and be closed, but I will risk it, as I need some good advice/experience on this.

I read the following at the ['About'](http://www.fogcreek.com/about.html) page of [Fog Creek Software](http://www.fogcreek.com/), the company that [Joel Spolsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky) founded and is CEO of:

> Back in the year 2000, the founders of Fog Creek, Joel Spolsky and
>   Michael Pryor, were having trouble finding a place to work where
>   programmers had decent working conditions and got an opportunity to do
>   great work, without bumbling, non-technical managers getting in the
>   way. Every high tech company claimed they wanted great programmers,
>   but they wouldn’t put their money where their mouth was.
>
> It started with the physical environment (with dozens of cubicles
>   jammed into a noisy, dark room, where the salespeople shouting on the
>   phone make it impossible for developers to concentrate). But it went
>   much deeper than that. Managers, terrified of change, treated any new
>   idea as a bizarre virus to be quarantined. Napoleon-complex junior
>   managers insisted that things be done exactly their way or you’re
>   fired. Corporate Furniture Police writhed in agony when anyone taped
>   up a movie poster in their cubicle. Disorganization was so rampant
>   that even if the ideas were good, it would have been impossible to
>   make a product out of them. Inexperienced managers practiced
>   hit-and-run management, issuing stern orders on exactly how to do
>   things without sticking around to see the farcical results of their
>   fiats.
>
> And worst of all, the MBA-types in charge thought that coding was a
>   support function, basically a fancy form of typing.

A ***blunt truth*** about most of today's big software companies! **Unfortunately** not every developer is as `gutsy` (or `lucky`, may I say?) as Joel Spolsky! So my question is:

**How best to work with such managers, keep them at bay and still deliver great work?**

Comment: I've marked this as off-topic, but it's still an interesting question. I suggest it might be better-asked at the Workplace.SE beta.

Comment: @GrahamLee Thanks! May someone with the right privileges please move the question?

Comment: Note that Joel Spolsky is advertising for his own company.  This implies that comparisons needs to be favorable.

Comment: @Curious I'll ask the Workplace mods if it's suitable for their site and move it for you if it is...

Comment: @Curious - The Workplace mods have said it's not suitable in it's current form. A reformulated version might be OK though.

Comment: Too bad!! This question was receiving some real good responses!

Comment: Could anyone please migrate this question? I don't have enough reputation (((

Comment: I've heard that when two people argue, the one who's smarter is the one to be blamed. We are to blame and we are to fix this

Answer (score 19):

While developers are perceived to be ignorant of the business problems, less technical managers will look down on developers. Developers need to learn the business cases and start driving or suggesting improvements in business terms. Once developers and managers are speaking the same language, things get easier.

This is as much about an attitude change. Yes, there will always be *ahem* stubborn individuals in management. However, creating an "us and them" attitude reinforces this from both sides.

Comment: +1 well put. A good programmer/manager tries to see the other end of the story.

Comment: If only I could upvote more than once...

Comment: Probably 90% of non-technical managers I have encountered didn't even understand the business problems quite as well as the developers.  I think its funny when the product owner asks me to start writing all the user stories because they are too hard.  It only makes sense that they more than double a developers salary while getting sent to run a booth at X convention in Las Vegas.

Answer (score 10):

Option 1 : Become manager yourself and show everyone how to do things right. You will probably find out it is not as easy as many programmers think.

Option 2 : Leave and find better place to work. I believe there are many big and small companies that at least know of this problem and try to solve it. With varying degrees of success.

Comment: I agree with what you say in Option 1, but often the managers themselves make it not so easy...
I have tried Option 2 (not solely for this reason) 7 times already! :) Still to be lucky! Thanks...

Comment: Seven times? Maybe it's not them that is the problem.. (sorry for being blunt)

Comment: @Curious: 7 times during how long period? Don't expect things to click into place immediately! You might need some patience.

Comment: @jgauffin I have already said 'not solely for this reason'! :)

Comment: @JoonasPulakka - over a period of 15+ years... :)

Comment: I expected to be bashed up when I mentioned that number 7 & I humbly accept that! But my question is not for discussing my own career (which anyway can not be undone now!), but for a general audience of Stack, particularly for the younger guys... Thanks everyone for the comments, answers!

Comment: @JoonasPulakka It definitely varies! At the places I've worked, if it took a new hire longer than 2-3 months to become valuable then serious questions would be asked. In fact, I'm curious: which sector(s) have you worked in where 2 years is acceptable?!

Comment: @Baqueta: Domain expert positions, developing high-tech measurement instruments, involving everything from embedded design to user interfaces. Of course an experienced person coming from similar is able to do *something* useful after a few months, but even 2 years is not sufficient to really learn such instruments thoroughly. And it's only when you know them thoroughly that you can really give your best. In this sort of fields, "lifetime" positions are probably a norm rather than an exception.

Comment: On point 1) the only thing hard about being a manager is mastering the politics to become one.  On point 2) My resume would be 14 pages long if I kept leaving places to find that extremely rare place. I will run out of companies to work for in this small city.

Answer (score 4):

Your job is to deliver great work. Managing is a support function, its purpose is to *enable* you to deliver great work - act as a buffer between you and the clients & stakeholders & politics & sales etc, remove obstacles, [abstract away everyday crap](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/DevelopmentAbstraction.html) that prevents you from achieving your best.

Think of the [memory manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management). It's not the boss that *commands* you and your programs, rather, it *frees* you from considering everything else that's going on in the computer, letting you to concentrate on what's essential for your program. That's what Joel is writing about, that's how managers *ideally* should work.

Not all managers are perfect, but nor are you. Nothing is. Unless things are totally crazy, then just suck it up and do the best you can, ignore what annoys you, and concentrate on *your* work. If you deliver great work, the managers will eventually respect and trust you more and let you work more in your way, once you've shown that you *can* deliver great work.

It's okay to work in a 70 % perfect organization. If your situation is really bad, then switch your employer. But don't give up too soon; the process of earning trust - convincing your managers and the organization of your abilities - can take years.

Answer (score 2):

> keep them at bay and still deliver great work

Good luck with that.  I started my own company and that's really all I can suggest.

Hopefully in situations like this, the engineers band together and if theres a real issue, either a technical project manager, a technical product manager, an architect or your own dev manager can understand the scope of your work, and keep nontechnical people out of your way.

But it doesnt always work that way.  I worked for a huge tech company once where the manager WAS supposedly technical and when the devs complained about non stop meetings with 4 different project managers day in and day out his response was - OK so you want MORE meetings with project managers.

I feel that over the last 10 years technical "talent" as in actual talent has been incredibly marginalized by the business side of software organizations and this is a problem for us careerwise.

Managing high paid developers with low paid business people is like sending your kid sister to lion taming school, it just doesnt work.

But one solution I will definitely side against, is lying.  I have seen really good developers try and ward off managers by filling them with stories that have no basis technically to get them to go away.  Dont do this, if you do, you have sold your soul, and thats worse than having a crappy job.